# Showing that two real matrices are not congruent over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe it is a stupid question but I will still ask it here.

How can I prove that the following matrices are not congruent over $\mathbb{R}$?

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \sqrt10\\
  \sqrt10 & -3\\
  \end{pmatrix}$
$  B=\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & \sqrt6\\
  \sqrt6 & -2\\
  \end{pmatrix}$

so I found the invertible matrices  $P$ and $Q$ such that $P^{t}AP$ and  $Q^{t}BQ$ are diagonal matrices. but does it help me ?
What am I missing here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are both congruent to the diagonal $(1,-1)$. So they are congruent. Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: @julien Sorry, but I think you are wrong. $A$ is diagonal to (-3,10/3) and $B$ is diagonal to (3,-4)

Comment: Yes. Both quadratic forms induced by $A$ and $B$ have the same signature $(1,-1)$. So they are congruent. Maybe what you call congruent is similar via an orthogonal matrix...But congruent is $A=P^TBP$ with $P$ simply invertible.

Comment: See [matrix congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) and [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).